# force a user to https:// and non www address format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a website that has an SSL setup for domain.com, but not www.domain.com.

I have the following running in my .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{HTTP_HOST}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This does not seem to work at all, basically I have a couple of scenarios

http://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
https://www.domain.com -> https://domain.com
http://domain.com -> https://domain.com

Basically I want anything that is not https://domain.com to be forwarded to https://domain.com, so that my SSL works without warnings.

Comment: You can not rewrite a request for `https://www.domain.com/` anywhere, if the browser does not connect in the first place because of an invalid certificate – it doesn’t _get_ to the point where you could do any rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```